# C: Correctly using fgets and sscanf. Not doing it quite right though

Tags: fgets, scanf

Here is the working code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct birthdate{
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        }birthdate_t;

typedef struct contacto {
        char name[30];
        long telephone;
        birthdate_t bd;  // es decir, bd es de tipo struct
        } contacto_t;

/* create the prototypes. Otherwise it does not work! */
contacto_t create_contact(void);
birthdate_t create_birthdate(void);

        contacto_t create_contact(){ // it returns a structure type
        contacto_t c1; // creates actually a blank structure y aquí abajo le meto datos

        printf("Enter name: ");
        fgets(c1.name, sizeof(c1.name), stdin);

        char line[256];
        printf("Enter telephone: ");
        fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
        if (sscanf(line, "%ld", &c1.telephone) != 1)
        {
            /* error in input */
        }

        printf("Enter birthdate");
        c1.bd = create_birthdate();
    }


        birthdate_t create_birthdate(){

            birthdate_t bd1;
            char dia[4];
            printf("Enter day: ");
            fgets(dia, sizeof(dia), stdin);
            sscanf(dia, "%d\n", &bd1.day);

            char mes[4];
            printf("Enter month: ");
            fgets(mes, sizeof(mes), stdin);
            sscanf(mes, "%d\n", &bd1.month);

            char anyo[6];
            printf("Enter year: ");
            fgets(anyo, sizeof(anyo), stdin);
            sscanf(anyo, "%d\n", &bd1.year);
            return bd1;
    } // end of birthdate function

main (void)
{
    create_contact();

}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What are you expecting `sscanf(c1.name, "%s", &c1.name);` to do?

Comment: What values? It's completely unclear what you're expecting the code to do. Look closely at `sscanf(c1.name, "%s", &c1.name);`. The only "value" referred to is `c1.name`. So should it save the value in `c1.name` in `c1.name`? What does that even mean? Similarly, `sscanf(bd1.day, "%d\n", &bd1.day);` only refers to `bd1.day`, which is an integer. But `sscanf` scans *input*. What *input* is it supposed to format? There's no source of input (other than an integer, which is necessarily already formatted to an integer) passed to it.

Comment: Similarly, where are you expecting `fgets(bd1.day, sizeof(bd1.day), stdin);` to store the string it reads in? `bd1.day` is an integer. It's not clear what you're expecting the code to do, but it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If you don't understand what a function does, don't use it. Either stick to functions whose operation you understand or ask how to do things you don't know how to do. Programming by guesswork, with no comments, not only won't work but will make it almost impossible for people to help you because they have no way to know what you were expecting the code to do.

Comment: I still have no idea what you think code like `sscanf(c1.telephone, "%d", &c1.telephone);` does. Reads from `c1.telephone` into `c1.telephone`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will always read with fgets but the way we proceed is different if we are reading a string or an integer or long.

When reading a string, once we use fgets that is it, no need to use sscanf.

If you are reading an integer then you use sscanf and convert it to integer.

Also, on what [Schwartz was talking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552770/c-correctly-using-fgets-and-sscanf-not-doing-it-quite-right-though#comment27292855_18552770) about: the syntax in sscanf when reading after fgets. It has 3 parameters and the one that reads in from stdin naturally has to have a different variable than the one that stores it.

But the reason that this was very confusing was that I was using sscanf also after using fgets to read a string, and also using wrong syntax which however did not give any problem because the compiler sort of would ignore it once the string was read by fgets, but however sscanf would give problems when reading an integer despite using the same syntax that I used for string that didn't give any problem.

Copying and pasting his right explanations, here it is:

fgets read a line of input from the given stream (e.g., stdin) and puts it into the given string variable (i.e., an array of chars).

So if you're just reading a string from a single line, there's nothing left to do after the fgets. The fgets in your previous post puts the line read (including the newline character) into the given string variable.

But if you want a true numeric value (as opposed to a string holding the characters making up the display version of the value) then you first read it as a string and then "scan" the string to convert the characters into a true number.

And it never makes sense to put the same variable name in the first and last positions of sscanf.